# Will repairing a MySQL table run the risk of data loss?

Tags: mysql, corruption, sql

I recently had a table in my MySQL DB go haywire (part of my Invision Power Board install) which has never happened to me before. If I use the "Repair" tool in phpMyAdmin, will I run the risk of data loss? Is there a more graceful way to restore the table to it's previous state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using MyISAM storage engine which is not transactional, so the risk of data loss is implied. But repairing a corrupted MyISAM table is a standard procedure, so you should not lose more than several latest records (usually one or two).

Comment: Very true. In fact, if the MyISAM is ROW_FORMAT is FIXED, there is an even lower incidence of data loss after REPAIR TABLE. +1 !!!